# TypeInitialization was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net program.  I added a Module to define all the global variables.  The problem I am having is when I try to set a value for any of the global variables in the main form, I get the error:

```
TypeInitialization was unhandled
```

The detailed error message is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' 
occurred in My_Program.exe

Additional information: The type initializer for 'My_Program.Module1' threw an exception.
```

Here is the line of code that triggers the error:

```
the_issue = "abc"
```

"the_issue" is a global variable defined in Module1.

What do I need to do to initialize my Module1?

here is the top of Module1:

```
Module Module1

Public loggedon As Boolean

Public market_open As Boolean

Public mlSymCount

Public order_cancelled(100)

Public simulate(100)

Public the_issue

Public issues(100)
```

Comment: If you comment out the line in question, does the code successfully start?  I suspect it may not.  Even better, could you provide enough code to reproduce the error?  There's not really enough info in this question for a complete answer.

Comment: Yes, the code runs great if the line in question is commented out.

Comment: Could you at least show the declaration for `the_issue`?

Comment: in your last question you were not **just** defining vaiarble's you were initializing them.  show the actual block of variables. please

Comment: here is the top of Module1:

Module Module1

    Public loggedon As Boolean

    Public market_open As Boolean

    Public mlSymCount

    Public order_cancelled(100)

    Public simulate(100)

    Public the_issue

    Public issues(100)

Comment: @RobLittle:  Thanks for providing that, but it's a bit unreadable shoved into a comment like that.  The comment system at all your line breaks.  Would you be able to add it to your original question formatted as code?

Comment: You should edit your post to add vital information like that, but I can see that you need to set `Option Strict On` - that will point out a number of issues